# OpenVPN: Routing by Destination Name OR Port, Not IP

Tags: routing, openvpn, router, route, dd-wrt

On a DD-WRT router, OpenVPN uses policy based routing for 192.168.1.128/25. If the VPN goes down, the firewall denies access to clients in the range.

I would like to add exceptions to the VPN routing.

**Is it possible to specify that connection to certain FQDNs will be sourced from the WAN address not the VPN address** (and of course be unencrypted)?

If not possible as above, at least **have connections to a certain port (587) be routed off VPN**, across the board?